# i want to align my check boxes like a grid

Tags: html, css, checkbox, alignment

i want make my check boxes to look cleaner and less space consuming by aligning it like a grid. But i seem to have problem aligning it with my images and also im having trouble with the spacing.

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/fb.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="engine" id="engine" value="google">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/twit.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="engine" id="engine" value="yahoo">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/googplus.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/link.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/pin.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/del.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/stumb.png" height="40px" width="55px">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/diig.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

this code is just a 1 column table , i would like to divide it to three and align them vertically, im not good at css so please help me

Comment: can you be a bit more specific with what you are after? I don't quite follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply width's to your cell's and do something like the following (not 100% what you are trying to achieve so please let me know if you need me to amend)...

```
<td width="15%">
```

but if you just want 3 columns where everything aligns do something like...

```
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/fb.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="engine" id="engine" value="google">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Your third column content
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/twit.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="engine" id="engine" value="yahoo">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Your third column content
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/googplus.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Your third column content
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/link.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Your third column content
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/pin.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Your third column content
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/del.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Your third column content
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/stumb.png" height="40px" width="55px">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Your third column content
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/diig.png" height="40px" width="40px">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="engine" value="bing">
                </td>
                <td>
                    Your third column content
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tonytansley/czo8rub2/

Comment: your suggestion works great! but now i know that the problem is not on my image. it seems that the width of my checkbox is too long.. any idea sir?

Comment: you need to do add this into your css style sheet...

    input[type=checkbox] {
      transform: scale(1.5);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    }

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tonytansley/czo8rub2/1/ updated to show the css working. you can edit the scale of the checkbox to suit

Comment: i got your suggestion working, turns out i just have and overlapping css, thank you sir

Comment: You're best to give your table a class eg. <table class="your-class"> and that way you can specify what you are targeting eg. table.your-class{

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this and let me know if it's what you're after.

http://jsfiddle.net/m4r3wve1/

You just need to use less `<tr>`. Not wrap every individual cell in it's own row.

Comment: ah i get it now, this makes sense

Comment: i tried that and it only scattered the images, i think its because of the width of the checkbox. i know your suggestion will work, i just need to reduce the width of my checkbox. sorry i didnt mentioned it here.. i noticed it just now

Comment: @KentAbrio If you can't get it working. Add it to a www.jsfiddle.net  and link it in the question. Makes it easier to address any other problems you might run into that way.

Answer (score 2):

A better option moving forward (although it will take time to get into this) is to use a responsive framework like [zurb foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html) which has a block component that alters its state dependant on screen size. This would be perfect for viewing this on mobile.

No disrespect intended but as you seem to be starting out with html and css, I'd get into this as it will speed things up for you.

You would use something like...

```
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-3">
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
  <li><!-- Your content goes here --></li>
</ul>
```